# How-to exclude terms from the main query the most performant way?

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts, pre-get-posts

This Q is [a follow up to this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41100/385) on the Q: ["How to exclude a specific term for the search?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/41069/385).

### 4 ways to filter out posts that have a specific term

```
Type                | Pro                   | Contra
--------------------------------------------------------
Run a new query     | Easy to implement     | Add. Queries
                                            | Add. time to execute the DB call + processing the parsing of the results
Inside the loop     | Easy to implement     | Sometimes Add. Queries
                                            | Add. time to execute
Modify the query    | Full control          | Hard to implement
                                            | Needs a lot of knowledge (preparing, DB interaction)
Add new query parts | No perform. impact    | Hard to get around
                    | Secure
                    | Full core support
```

The first type *imho* is *not* an option. The "Types" 2 & 3 are already answered in the other Q and both still have some backdraws.

#### Question:

1. How to add an additional `tax_query` argument to the main query using (for e.g.) the `pre_get_posts` filter?
2. Do you know additional ways to modify the main query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the taxonomy query for the main query using pre_get_posts:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_exclude_terms_from_query' );
function my_exclude_terms_from_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() /* && whatever else */ ) {
        $tax_query = array (
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'terms' => array( 'cat-slug' ),
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

If `tax_query` is already set and you need to modify it instead, you can grab and then add to the `$tax_query` array.

Comment: That's a pretty good approach and mostly overseen. +1. As there are no other answers so far, I'll set this is as solution. Thanks! :)