# Include and Exclude Taxonomies From Archives & Feeds Using 'pre_get_posts'

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, feed, pre-get-posts

### What I am trying to do?

My blog uses a custom taxonomy called `edition` with terms like `us-canada` (6), `eu` (7) and `india` (8) -- term slug (ID).

I want to make sure that posts **not assigned to any specific 'edition'** be shown under all the terms (i.e. if a post is not assigned to usa, europe or india, it'll be shown in the archive pages of all these terms).

### What I've tried?

Here's the sample code pertaining to one of the terms, which should give you an idea of what I am exactly trying to do, and what I'd be doing wrong.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','better_editions_archive');

function better_editions_archive($query) {

    if ( $query->is_tax( 'edition', 6 ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );

        $query->set( 'tax_query',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 1, 2, 4, 5 )
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 7, 8 ),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

**What's wrong?** The aforementioned code doesn't work (others I've tried: [code-1](http://paste.kde.org/693992/), [code-2](http://paste.kde.org/693998/)), it's doesn't change anything. There's no debug error either.

So, what could I be doing wrong?

**ALSO**, to make sure that the changes also apply to feeds of these terms, I replaced the relevant line in the aforementioned code with this:

```
function better_editions_archive($query) {

    if ( ( $query->is_tax( 'edition', 6 ) && $query->is_main_query() ) || ( $query->is_feed() && $query->is_tax( 'edition', 6 ) ) ) {
```

But that starts to redirect the terms' feeds back to the terms' archives. That is, with the function in place, `example.com/edition/usa/feed/` redirects back to `example.com/edition/usa/`.

Again, I've no clue as to what I'd be doing wrong.

### UPDATE: What's worked for me? (But...)

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'better_editions_archive' );

function better_editions_archive( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'edition', 6 ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',

            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 1, 2, 4, 5 )
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 7, 8 ),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );

        $query->query_vars = $args;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

It works, but the problem is, I'd an extended chat discussion with a knowledgeable WordPress developer, and he told me this (you can follow the [full conversation here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8450658#8450658), but it's too lengthy):

> And you're then assigning this array as the `query_vars`. Now the `query_vars` is a pretty large object. And you're basically overwriting the data in there and just adding your custom ones. This means that you 'unset' everything that is added per default.

He pretty much advised against using this solution, and instead go with the `$query->set();` method.

But as you can see far above, I couldn't get the other one to work. So I am here to see if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, in a less-technical-speak.

Comment: There is a missing `)` to close the `set` method of `$query->set( 'tax_query', `

Comment: @birgire I just noticed your comment as I was about to make an edit. There wasn't any missing `)` initially either (the `set` is actually closed, and the closing `);` is in another line further below). Can you please take a good look at the code?

Comment: Use the tax_query array on the $query->set method. The developer have right, you overwrite all on query and it is better, if you enhance the query.

Comment: @bueltge [Is this](http://paste.kde.org/693992/) what you want me to try? If so, I tried it. It didn't work. If not, can you be a bit more clear? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify in what way it isn't working? Are you getting no results at all? Or just not the combination of results that you expect?

Comment: @vancoder yeah, like I said, nothing's changing i.e., it's just the same with/without the function in place. I am getting no results at all!

Comment: The first nested array of the tax_query specified the taxonomy as 'category'. Is this correct? or should it be 'edition'?

Comment: @vancoder As per my understanding that's how it should be. The first array should say 'show posts from all categories' while the second array should override it a little and say, if post(s) belong(s) to any other custom taxonomy (edition) term than the term's archive you are looking at, don't show it. Get the idea of what I am trying to do here? Wondering if that isn't clear in my question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm 100% certain of what you're after, but I've edited my answer based on an educated guess.

Comment: @Thone: I mean this, what now in the answer `$query->set( 'tax_query', array() )` ;) Yesterday was it not possible for me to write a answer, I readed on my mobile.

Comment: @bueltge I am already doing that. Please see the first code block.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll take another shot.

The following should modify the main query, such that it will include in its loop any posts that belong to *no term of the Edition custom taxonomy*.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','better_editions_archive');

function better_editions_archive( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_tax( 'edition' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $terms = get_terms( 'edition', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $terms,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that. It didn't change anything. No debug errors/suggestions either. Thanks for trying. :)

Comment: As a debugging method, you can try print_r($query) on your first sample code. Somewhere in the output there should be the SQL being generated. Add it here, it might be useful.

Comment: Jsut to check - you are on WP 3.5 +, right?

Comment: Yes, the latest version of WordPress (always!). And for the debug, you want me to replace `return $query;` with `print_r($query);`? Is that what you want me to do?

Comment: If yes, here's what I got: http://paste.kde.org/694496/ -- Does that say something? (I didn't understand it.)

Comment: Oh my god, that worked! And without any further changes it's also modifying the feeds of the custom taxonomy terms just as it does to the terms' archives (which is, of course, what I want). Is this how it works or am I just dreaming? Don't we need to add something like something like `( is_feed() && is_.... )`?

Comment: It should work on any term page under the Edition taxonomy. I don't know about feeds. I'll take the bounty of it's working though :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note to self:** @vancoder's answer is basically a better (& automated) version of this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','better_editions_archive');

function better_editions_archive($query) {

    if ( $query->is_tax( 'edition') && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );

        $query->set( 'tax_query',
            array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 6, 7, 8 ),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );

    }

    return $query;
}
```

**(What the code says)** If it's the archive for any term that belongs to the custom taxonomy '`edition`', then...

1. The code doesn't mess with the default function of the terms' archive pages, i.e., posts assigned to a term of the custom taxonomy '`edition`' will (as usual) be shown in the relevant term's archive.
2. But if a post is not assigned to any of the given custom taxonomy's terms (see `'terms' => array( 6, 7, 8 )` and `'operator' => 'NOT IN'`), then show such posts in the archive pages of all the terms of the custom taxonomy.
3. The code also affects the feeds of the said terms, and therefore, the feeds mirror the content of archive pages, which is just what I need. In case you don't want the feeds to be affected i.e. if you want the changes to only apply to the archive pages replace the IF with this:

   ```
   if ( $query->is_tax( 'edition') && $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->is_feed() ) {
   ```