# Exclude 2 in 3 terms of A Taxonomy from all Archives

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives, terms, pre-get-posts

I have read this post:
[Include and Exclude Taxonomies From Archives & Feeds Using 'pre_get_posts'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90220/include-and-exclude-taxonomies-from-archives-feeds-using-pre-get-posts)

And then I have used that function to my theme.
My Taxonomy (tinh-trang) had 3 term: 19,20,21 And I want to exclude all post have terms id: 19, 21 when visitor go to any archives.

But I have nothing changed?

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','change_archive_loop');

function change_archive_loop( $query ) {
    $choduyet = intval(get_option('zen-id_cho_duyet')); // Get term ID 1 from theme option
    $baocao = intval(get_option('zen-id_bao_cao')); // Get term ID 2 from theme option
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'tinh-trang' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $terms = array($choduyet, $baocao);
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tinh-trang',
                'field' => 'id',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                'terms' => $terms
            )
        ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few remarks:

- I use `pre_get_posts` as an action hook, not as a filter.
- You should use `! is_admin()` to prevent this from changing your backend views.
- You should skip the `'relation' => 'OR',` since you only have a single `tax_query` filter
- Is there any reason why you have to modify the post type ? Is your custom taxonomy attached to multiple post types?

so you could try this modification instead:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_archive_loop' );

function change_archive_loop( $query ) {
    $choduyet = intval( get_option( 'zen-id_cho_duyet' ) );
    $baocao = intval( get_option( 'zen-id_bao_cao' ) );
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_tax( 'tinh-trang' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $terms = array( $choduyet, $baocao );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tinh-trang',
                'field' => 'id',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                'terms' => $terms
            )
        ) );
    }
 }
```

Comment: This works on my install in a custom taxonomy archive and excludes the selected terms. Can you add some debug info, like the var_dump on $terms?

Comment: Thanks you very much! I have a problem in that function, so when I change `$query->is_tax( 'tinh-trang' )` to `$query->is_category()` it's works!

Comment: ok great to hear you got it working ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclude like this.

```
    $posts = get_posts(  array( 'numberposts'   => -1,
                                'exclude'       => array('post_id_1', 'post_id_2'),
                                'post_type'     => 'post_type',
                                'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
                                'meta_key'      => 'post_meta_key',
                                'order'         => 'DESC',
                                'tax_query'     => array('relation'=> 'OR',
                                                        array(  'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy_1',
                                                                'field'     => 'id',
                                                                'terms'     => 'taxonomy_id_1'
                                                                )),
                                                        array(  'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy_id_2',
                                                                'field'     => 'id',
                                                                'terms'     => 'taxonomy_id_2'
                                                                )),
                                'meta_query'    => array(array( 'key' => 'meta_key',
                                                                'value' => 'meta_value'
                                                            ))
                                            )
                                    );
```

If you want to use relation in 'meta_query' also then write the same code as write in 'tax_query'.

You can also use 'wp_query' instead of 'get_posts'.