# How to not have the items of the subtaxonomy within the parent taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

What I'm trying to do: Have a script that will go trough every taxonomy of a custom post type, then list the posts that are with that taxonomy.

Code:

```
<?php $taxos = get_categories( 'taxonomy='.$taxonomy.'&post_type='.$type.'&orderby=term_group' ); ?>
<?php if($taxos) : foreach($taxos as $taxoOnglet) : ?>

<?php
    $ongletQuery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        $taxonomy => $taxoOnglet->slug,
        'showposts' => -1,
        'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
    ));
?>

[...]loop for showing the posts[...]

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I do get all my posts with that query fine, but there is a problem. The parent taxonomies list their children's posts, even if the post is only attributed to the children.

Which gives me something like this

```
PARENT TAXONOMY
Post A
Post B

CHILD A
Post A

CHILD B
Post B
```

So I'm trying to find a way to remove the A and B posts from the parent taxonomy, so they will only appear in the child where they are attributed. Is there a way to do this with the WP_Query of WP?

Comment: See the edit to my answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43345/6477

Answer (score 0):

You may well be able to do this with the taxonomy query parameter you can pass to the WP_Query object. You'll find it on the codex, look for `include_children`. Sadly I'm short on time or else I'd try and put some code together to help out more...