# Display only post types that are direct children of the current taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I have a hieratical category structure using Taxonomies, with a custom post displayed within them.

Currently the higher level categories display all the posts that are in their child categories. How do I make it only list from the current category only and not their children.

I'm currently using the default code.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I'm not a programmer and have not been ably to find anything with an exact or close enough match for me to work it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to only show posts on last child category](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163572/how-to-only-show-posts-on-last-child-category)

Comment: I'm not sure it is a duplicate but is similar.. The solution ciprianmocanu gave is easier to implement or at least understand.

Comment: You should never change the main query for a custom one. The 2nd solution by @ialocin is the correct way to achieve this. And that solution is real easy

Comment: Where should I put it? I've tried both before and after if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  with no luck.

Comment: Add it in functions.php

Comment: Ahh that makes sense but does not appear to be doing anything.. Do I need to set the post type or taxonomy that it applies to somewhere?

Comment: If it is a custom taxonomy page, change `&& $query->is_category()` to `&& $query->is_tax('NAME OF YOUR CUSTOM TAXONOMY')`

Comment: I'm afraid it's still showing them. I've put and <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> back in and put the add_filter code at the bottom of functions.php.. Have I missed something?

Comment: on which page/template are you doing this

Comment: taxonomy-taxonomy_name.php

Comment: Strange, then it should work with `is_tax()`

Comment: Ahhh my bad.. It looks like that last change didn't upload. Sorry... It's working perfectly now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should do about the answer below now as it is technically works but not the correct method.. Should I un-accept it?

Comment: My pleasure. No, you can just leave it as-is. This question is already marked duplicate and should be closed soon anyway. BTW, that answer is also valid, but not recommended. It does create problems as you have seen, custom queries in place of a main query is always a bit troublesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)? Using my knowledge and the [WP_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), I did this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type', //change the post type here
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_category', //change the taxonomy name here
            'field' => 'id',
            'include_children' => false,
            'terms' => 10 //change the term id here 
        )
    )
);
$_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($_query->have_posts()):
    while ($_query->have_posts()):
        $_query->the_post();
        
        //do something here the_title() etc
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

The magic should come from the `include_children` attribute. Test it out :)

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: It took me a short while to implement it but correctly but it worked perfectly. 
I inserted the term id using the code below.

 $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
 $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;

Comment: You may want to clarify that it replaces <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>