# Hide child term posts on parent term pages

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I have created a custom post "company" and custom category "company category". I have a question here, I want to hide child category post in primary category.

For Example:

- Primary Category "First"

  - Sub Category "Second"

I've created two posts "Fname" and "Sname". "Fname" was assign to First category and "Sname" assign to Second Category. I don't want  show "Sname" in First category but just "Fname" be display on First category.

Is this possible?

I found a plugin solutions, [Just One Category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/just-one-category/),
But all of them are used for normal post type , not custom post type.

I try edit the code like this:

```
$q_args = array(
    'paged' => $glocal_search_pageds,
    'post_type' => array('company'),
    's' => $s,
    'company_category' => $company_category,
    'posts_per_page' => $companyprp,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'include_children' => false
          )
      )
);
```

Comment: It is good practice to show us the code you have tried already, working or not, or at least what you have investigated to solve the problem (more than test a plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to hook into the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook. First, it is checked if we are in an archive of your custom taxonomy, then set `include_children` to `false` for the [`tax_query` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) of the query.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cyb_pre_get_posts' );
function cyb_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    //Assuming the slug of the custom taxonomy is company-category
    //change it with the correct value if needed
    if( $query->is_tax( 'company-category' ) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'company-category',
                'terms'            => $query->get( 'company-category' ),
                'include_children' => false
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Another approach that seems better (taken from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163572/how-to-only-show-posts-on-last-child-category) and adapted for custom taxonomy instead of core category taxonomy):

```
add_filter( 'parse_tax_query', 'cyb_do_not_include_children_in_company_category_archive' );
function cyb_do_not_include_children_in_company_category_archive( $query ) {
    if ( 
        ! is_admin() 
        && $query->is_main_query()
        && $query->is_tax( 'company-category' )
    ) {
        $query->tax_query->queries[0]['include_children'] = 0;
    }
}
```

For custom queries and secondary loops (see [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)):

```
 $args = array(
             //Rest of you args go here
             'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'include_children' => false
                  )
              )
          );

 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I still thinks that the answer from @ialocin is better for this job as it is filtering the current tax query. :-)

Comment: Yes, it looks better. I didn't notice your comment. The answer of @ialocin checks for`is_category()`, changing that for `is_tax()` should work for this, as this question is for custom taxonomy.

Comment: Yes, it does work with `is_tax()`, actually had the same question a while ago. There is unfortunately not an answer as we solved this in comments. But, yes, I can confirm that it works. +1

Comment: yes it's work but when i search category from search mean with ?s=&company_category=firstcategory&cat=firstcategory&search_simple=search it will show all listing again .. have anyway to hide it ?

Comment: That is because the code checks `$query->is_tax('company-category')`. That means that it is executed only for 'company-category' archives, as that is what you asked. [You can add/remove more conditionals as you need](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties). For search archives you could use `$query->is_search()`

Comment: i have already try is_search('company_category') is not working also ...my search link is something like this in the behind **/?s=&company_category=restaurant&cat=restaurant&search_simple=search**

Comment: @JackLee you are using a custom query in a page template for search results. I know this beacuse you posted that information on another question. If you read the code of my answer, it checks for `$query->is_main_query()` and in your search page you are not in the main query, you are in a custom query. See the edited answer, I've added relevant code for custom queries and secondary loops.

Comment: @cybmeta hi thank for reply ..i try to edit the code but it's pop out with no search result 


`$q_args =array(
'paged' => $glocal_search_pageds,'post_type' => array('company'),'s' => $s,'company_category' => $company_category,'posts_per_page' => $companyprp,'orderby' => $orderby,'order' => $order,'tax_query' => array(array('include_children' => false) ));`