# Show child terms of current term of the taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have some taxonomies (such as product, articles &...) and any taxonomy has some terms (Eg for product: mobile, book & ...), and any terms has some child terms (Eg for mobile: iPhone, sumsung, htc &... ).

Now my question:

When anybody go to any term page (**not** child term page) such as mobile (through taxonomy.php **not** taxonomy-product-mobile.php), on this page all child terms of the term will be shown (iPhone, sumsung, htc &...) with their loop posts (iPhone posts).

[for example i click on the Mobile from site menu]

```
Welcome to Mobile store:
   iPhone
      post one
      post two
      post three
   sumsung
      post one
      post two
      post three
   htc
      post one
      post two
      post three
```

Comment: [Try this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169675/1685), which shows how to set term archives to *not* include term children.