# Custom Taxonomy Template not respecting 'include_children' => 'false'

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I've created a custom taxonomy, for a custom post type, and created a custom page for it, the usual, etc.

Problem is I want to only show the custom posts that are part of the category, and not show the posts from the sub categories. So I wrote the following query for the loop:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'include_children' => 'false' ) );
query_posts( $args );
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Although `'include_children' => 'false'` is included in the `$args` it still shows the products from the subcategories. I tried changing it for `'post_parent' => 0`, and using them both at the same time, but to no avail.

Here is the code for my taxonomy:

```
function productcat_taxonomy() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Product Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Product Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Product Category Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Product Categories' ),
  );    

  register_taxonomy('product-category',array('product'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product-category' ),
  ));

}

add_action( 'init', 'productcat_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it matters in WP, but the value is supposed to be a boolean, and you are passing false as a string.

Comment: @gdaniel thanks for that - although it unfortunately makes no difference - an error all the same

Comment: See here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169673/hide-child-term-posts-on-parent-term-pages

Comment: @hkchakladar thanks for the link, but strangely enough I can't seem to make it work. Care to post an answer with more detail? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. As @gdaniel said, you are giving a string in place of boolean value.
   Replace `'include_children' => 'false'` to `'include_children' => false`
   (Remove quote from `false`)
2. You can hook into the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to change the query vars before getting the posts. And when on custom taxonomy template page, include your custom query to the global query. This goes to themes `functions.php`

---

```
function wpse239243_exclude_child( $query ) {

    //if on frontend custom taxonomy template
    if( $query->is_tax( 'product-category' ) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {

        $tax_query = array( array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'product-category',
            'terms'            => $query->get( 'product-category' ),
            'include_children' => false
        ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse239243_exclude_child' );
```

Comment: Point 1 I tried before (as noted in the comments) and it makes no change. Point 2 causes an Error 500 when enabled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There was a lot of hard coding going on in a number of these answers that I felt like may have disadvantages further down the road. Here is an approach that takes the existing tax_query, and swaps out the "include_children" argument.

As an aside, I did not have any luck setting "include_children" to false in this instance. I only found a zero to work.

```
function wpse239243_exclude_child_taxonomies( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if (is_tax('product-category')) {
            $tax_query = $query->tax_query->queries;
            $tax_query[0]['include_children'] = 0;
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
    return;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse239243_exclude_child_taxonomies', 1 );
```

Comment: This is the solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `'include_children' => 'false'`, but you haven't told WordPress [which taxonomy this is about](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and also not what the base category is you don't want the children of. You would do that as follows:

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'product-category',
        'include_children' => 'false' 
        'terms'            => 'base-category-ID',
    ) ),
);
```

Instead of a fixed `base-category-ID`, you can off course use a variable containing the name of the first category on the current post:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
```