# Archive pagination causing 404 with permalinks structure

Tags: categories, permalinks, pagination, 404-error

Somehow my `archive.php` is causing some problems because I'm using `/%category%/%postname%/` as my permalink structure.

The `next_posts_link()` redirects to `/category/page/2`: which causes an 404 error.
After changing my permalink structure to `/%category%/` the pagination works fine, but I can't access any single posts or pages.

I've installed several plug-ins of course. The one that could affect the permalink structure is Yoast SEO, but after deactivating it still doesn't work.

Anyone knows what this problem can cause?
Thanks in forward!

Comment: Deactivate all plugins one by one, switch to a bundled theme, flush your permalinks and clear all caches. Make sure that your permalink structure is working on a vanilla install. If everty thing works on a vanilla install, it is not server specific and cannot be the `htaccess` file. It will be a plugin or your theme causing this. There is no other way that I know of to debug the issue

Comment: I've got it working again. I've deactivated some plugin, change my permalinks a few times and reset the `categorybase` in the permalink tab. I don't exactly know what caused the problem, but it's fixed. Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it. This sometimes the best debugging route to take with any issue where you do not have any debugging error or php errors