# Remove WHERE conditions from search query

Tags: search

The native search page runs a query like so:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%keyword%') 
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%keyword%')) 
AND (wp_posts.post_password = '') 
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I am passing specific post IDs to the query by hooking into pre_get_posts so I don't need the other `WHERE` conditions related to the keyword. e.g.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_search_filter');
function my_search_filter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
            // post IDs within distance X
        $matches = array(1,3,5);
        $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $matches;

    }
}
```

How can I remove the conditions related to post_title and post_content from the query object by modifying the existing query rather than writing a new one.

Comment: Why are you using a search if you don't want to actually search anything...? Could you give a brief outline of what you are trying to achieve - there is probably a better than modifying a search query :D

Comment: I'm geocoding the address the user enters in the search form to build a list of matching post IDs within a certain distance which I store in $matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) or [`posts_search`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/posts_search?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/query.php). See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41100/4771) for a couple of examples.