# I need a custom search page to lead to search.php but it goes to index.php

Tags: search

I built a custom search page with a form like:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
```

trouble is I want the results to appear in search.php

whereas I m led to index.php

How can I force to always go to search.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correctly Wordpress loads the search template dynamically by the parameters delivered to it. Specifically the `s` parameter. Meaning if you try to send the user to the `http://www.example.com/search.php` you'll get 404 error page.
For now the only workaround I can think is to create a function which is hooked to the `init` action hook that listens for a parameter in order to load the right file. The function must reside in the `functions.php` of your theme (assuming you are developing a theme). The function goes like this:

```
function load_custom_search_template(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['custom_search'])){
        require('my_search.php');
        die();
    }
}
add_action('init','load_custom_search_template');
```

Comment: This is an excellent idea. I will try it asap.
I can't thank you enough already for the valuable input.

Comment: You're absolutely welcome.

Comment: `init` is the _wrong_ hook for this.

Comment: Well I guess there a number of other hooks that can be used for this but `init` works for me. Simply stating it's _wrong_ will not help anyone. Please explain why you think it's wrong.

Comment: It workked ok for me

Answer (score 3):

### Template tag for the rescue

Simply use [`get_search_form( $echo )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_search_form/) for the search form.

This template tag first searches for a `searchform.php` file in your main theme folder. If there is no such template, then you'll get a default search form. And depending on your input argument, you can echo or just return it for later use. It also has a filter on its end, that contains the complete search form HTML as string: `get_search_form` with one argument: `$form_html`.

### How and what to use for search form modifications

So if you want to alter the output, just append, prefix, replace whatever...

- use the `get_search_form`-filter to pre-/append something or completely replace the form
- use the custom template to build a unique search form

Or get really sophisticated with theme structure and use the filter to load your searchform from somewhere in your nested theme structure:

```
// In your functions.php
function wpse65934_searchform_location( $form )
{
    return get_template_part( 'subfolder/searchform', 'default' );
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpse65934_searchform_location' );
```

Comment: Thanks your first proposal worked!
I cant use  get_search_form because I have a very complex set of criteria, so I design the form myself. I want to allow my users to search posts by 
* author
* tag
* category
* contained text
therefore I build my form from scratch.
Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @p.a. Glad it helped, but please mark the answer as solution: Use the ✓-check mark below the voting arrows on the upper right of this answer. Btw: Search for the `posts_clauses`-filter in questions (and maybe my name) to see how you can alter the search query properly. If you don't get around by yourself, simply open another question.

Comment: why would I need to work with posts_clauses? Why not with WP_Query(args) where args contains tags, authors, categories and string criteria?
BTW I checked your first answer, which solved my pain.

Comment: @p.a. Sorry: Which first answer? Ad WP_Query) You add another query, so why not simply alter the original one? That's why WP got this filter: make things quick and keep DB + memory pressure low.

Comment: can ou refer to posts_clauses article? An introductory one pls

Comment: @p.a. [Read into this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/exclude-specific-term-from-search/41100#41100).

Comment: Just a note that get_template_part() does not return HTML, so the example function would likely print two search forms, the default one and the one from the "nested theme structure." That is to say that get_template_part() acts like php's "include" or "require."

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hidden input of keyword search, as it'll redirect to the **search.php** template

```
<input type="hidden" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
```