# how would I create a custom query to get all users, and a related post based on a postmeta field?

Tags: query, mysql

I have about 50 users.  Its pretty easy to list them all.  However they are related to a special custom post type through a postmeta field called wpp_agents.

So I need to list Users, but also the post title(linked to the post).

1. User 1 | User 1's Post(linked)
2. User 2 | User 2's Post(linked)
3. etc...

I am a mysql noob but getting pretty ok with php.

Here is what I am playing with:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT $wpdb->users*,
        "SELECT display_name, user_email 
     FROM $wpdb->users 
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta ON
      user.ID=wpp_agents;",
    ARRAY_A
);
```

but its not right.

I believe I need to 
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->users
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta

but then not sure.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gladly there's a function that will output **exactly that query string** for you (still laughing about it :) ).

Here it is: [`get_posts_by_author_sql` <sup>@queryposts.com</sup>](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts_by_author_sql/), which looks in the core source [like this](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L4200).

In detail it builds the `WHERE` part for you, that you can drop into your query.

So just throw the user ID in and build your string that you can use in your query:

```
foreach ( $users as $user )
{
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'wpp_agents', true, $user->ID );

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $where );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

[Take a look at this question on how to intercept the `posts_clauses` (or even better the `posts_where`) filter.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/exclude-specific-term-from-search/41100#41100)

Maybe you find a way to simply alter the main query to spit this out on a single call. Hint: You should have some serious caching mechanism or add the result as transient. This can get intense.

Comment: ok so being ok at php I think I am understanding what your getting at here. The challenge is that post_type=property in this case.  wpp_agents is the postmeta table field that contains the related user->ID.  So postmeta records for post->ID 29 has a wpp_agents value of 3, which is the user-ID I am already querying.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: You see the function and you can read what arguments you can throw in - exchange what you need, come back with an update and a dump.

Comment: I am going to keep playing with this stuff but I decided to go at the issue from the other end.  Listing the posts, then using the postmeta->wpp_agents value to find a user.  IF I was dealing with a large db, this would not be a good way to go because I think it taxes the db to heavily but with 20 posts and 50 users, its not overkill.