# Filter keywords from search query

Tags: filters, search, exclude

I have search over the google, somewhere out there and here(http://wordpress.stackexchange.com). But, i can't seem to get the solution i was looking for.

I would like to ask that, is there any solution which allows me to exclude the words i wanted to filter from search queries? Example: **when visitors using my search box, they type "email" and search, the result returns to no post found with this keyword.**. All the post contains the word of "email". But, i don't want visitors to get the search result by searching email. I want them to get the best related result.

I found this question([Exclude Specific Term from Search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/exclude-specific-term-from-search)), i think that this question is similar to what i am asking here. But, i don't understand how it works.

I wanted to exclude a few words that hiding from search result so that visitors won't get result with non related post. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer but reading through your question again, I'm not sure what you're after so I hope I'm not misunderstanding it ;-)

Comment: Hi @birgire, you got what i mean. I commented to your answer for less than 5 minutes time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're not looking for the  `wp_search_stopwords` filter type of solution.

So here's a modification of the great answer by @kaiser that you referred to:

```
/**
 * Exclude array of words from all search queries in the front-end
 *
 * Modification of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41100/26350 by @kaiser
 */

add_filter( 'posts_search', function( $search, $q )
{
    // Target all search queries in the front-end:
    if( is_admin() || ! $q->is_search() ) return $search;

    global $wpdb;

    $exclude_words = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]; // <-- Modify this to your needs!

    $sql = " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title   NOT LIKE '%%%s%%' 
             AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_content NOT LIKE '%%%s%%' ";

    foreach( (array) $exclude_words as $word )
        $search .= $wpdb->prepare(
           $sql,
           $wpdb->esc_like( $word ),
           $wpdb->esc_like( $word )
        );

    return $search;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where you have to modify the `$exclude_words` to your needs. Here we target all search queries in the front-end.

Notice the `'%%%s%%'` part. It will be transformed into `'%someword%'` in the generated SQL query. It's also tempting to use `%1$s` for repeating use of the same string, but it's not supported by `$wpdb->prepare()`. If we would use `sprintf` instead, we have to make sure it's not translated into the `$s` variable within a string with double quotes: `"$s"`.

If we only want to modify the main search query, we could use:

```
    if( is_admin() || ! $q->is_main_query() || ! $q->is_search() ) return $search;
```

instead of this check:

```
    if( is_admin() || ! $q->is_search() ) return $search;
```

**Update:**

We can now search with `foo -bar` to exclude `bar` from the `foo` search.

Then one could play with something like:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if ( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search() )
        $q->set( 's', $q->get( 's' ) . ' -bar' );

} );
```

Note that the search exclusion prefix can be changed with the  `wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix` filter.

Comment: Hi! @birgire, I tried your code and add the words that i want to filter to the `$exclude_words`. It works fine with the search result. But, it leads some of my post returning to `Page Not Found`. Do you have any idea on this issue?

Comment: So you get a 404 for no search results found? Does that happen without this code snippet? @Jornes

Comment: Hi @birgire, nope! The search result was fine. All the posts contained the words i have filtered are not turning up when using the search box. But, i get 404 error page for when i visit all the posts which contained the words i have filtered using the code you provided. Do you know how to fix it up? Thanks!

Comment: ok, please try the updated answer @Jornes where I target all search queries. You might want to restrict it to the main query search instead, by using `is_search()`.

Comment: HI @birgire, awesome! It works now. Thank you so much! By the way, what was the issue in previous code?

Comment: ok great. The SQL part from the `posts_search` filter is appended to the WHERE part of the generated SQL query so it's not specifically restricted to the search queries. So we needed to adjust for that, by checking if  `$q->is_search()` is true for the current query `$q`. We also don't want to modify the search queries in the backend, hence the `is_admin()` check. Another approach would be to check if the `$search` string in the filter is empty or not, and then append to it. @Jornes

Comment: Although this is great, wp should absolutely offer an option that allows people to simply substitute or remove words from the `s` parameter used for searching.

Comment: @MrMesees Have you tried a search like: `foo -bar` to exclude `bar` from the `foo` search? This is supported. It's also possible to remove search words from the search query before it hits the database, via code but it might have various edge cases.